# $\mathsf kth$ moment of the standard deviation about the origin from a $\mathsf N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ population

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let T be the standard deviation of a random sample of size n from a $\mathsf N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ normal population. Find the $\mathsf kth$ moment of T about the origin, and state the condition for the existence of this moment.

Basically we are being asked to find $\mathsf E[T^k]$. So should I do something by finding the distribution of the standard deviation or can we infer something from the behaviour of the random variable of interest.

Can we write it as,

$\mathsf E[\sigma^k] = \int \sigma^k pdf d\sigma$

if its true how do we find out the distribution of the standard deviation. Will the standard deviation also follow a normal distribution.

Comment: Your question is undefined. If, by _standard deviation_, you intend the square root of the _sample variance_, you need to define what estimator of _sample variance_ you intend to use. There are two versions in common usage.

Comment: what is the other version of usage ?

Comment: Other is brother to another mother.

Comment: can we say that the equation in the question shown as $\mathsf E[T^k]$ is the kth moment of the standard deviation and the condition for it to exist is that k<3. Since the first moment will be the expectation of the standard deviation, the second moment will be the expectation of the variance. Third moment of $\mathsf \sigma$ doesnt exist.

Comment: How do we find out what distribution it follows.